Next.js using Link in client component back to other page doesn't apply layout
EDIT:
I've found what was messing up. I was wrapping my subpages return elements into main layout component. My bad. Thanks for answers guys.
so I have a problem with the Link component. I have an app directory with layout.tsx, page.tsx, and directory /about. When I'm using Link in page.tsx to go to /about it works fine, layout is applied. In about I have client component. In that component when I use Link with href='/' to go back to the main page components from page.tsx are applied but layout.tsx is not. I've added console logs to the layout and page. When I'm trying to go back from /about none of the console logs is displayed in the terminal. Here is the code:
layout.tsx:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  console.log('layout')
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head></head>
      <body className={styles.main}>
          <VideoBackground />
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

page.tsx:
export default async function Page() {
  const plants = await getPlants()
  console.log('plants page')
  return (
        <PlantsGrid 
          plants={plants}
        />
  );
}

and link in client component:
<div className={styles.RightContent}>
          <div className={styles.Button} onClick={props.update ? updatePlant : sendNewPlant}>{props.update ? 'Zapisz' : 'Dodaj'}</div>
          <Link href='/'><div className={styles.CancelButton}>{changesMade ? 'Anuluj' : 'Wróć'}</div></Link>
        </div>
      </div>

I've tried using <a> and it worked but I want to know why going back with Link isn't working

I've just checked and using Link with href='/' from other page.tsx to main one also doesn't apply layout. But using Link from main page.tsx to some subpage apply layout

It maybe because of hydration issue. Since layout render on server and Link is inside a client component.
Client components sometimes cause unpredictable issues with the nextjs App router layout
you can try navigating with useRouter() hook instead of Link
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation';

     const ClientComponent = () => {
     
        const router = useRouter();
       
        return (
           <div className={styles.RightContent}>
            <div className={styles.Button} onClick={props.update ? updatePlant : 
              sendNewPlant}>{props.update ? 'Zapisz' : 'Dodaj'}</div>
            <div className={styles.CancelButton} onClick={() => router.push('/')}>
               {changesMade ? 'Anuluj' : 'Wróć'}
            </div>
           </div> 
         );
    };


Thanks for answer, unfortunately it's still doesn't apply layout. Also I've just checked and using Link from other page.tsx  to main page.tsx also doesn't apply layout
